# Como substituir mais de um caractere no método "replace()" em Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Eu tenho o texto e preciso retirar todos os sinais de pontuação usando apenas um método `replace()`, sem usar laço também.

A minha ideia inicial seria usar `texto.replace('.', '')`, isto para cada tipo de pontuação, mas gostaria de simplificar.

Comment: Testou pra ver se isso dá certo?

Comment: Reverti a adição de tag, pois o autor não necessariamente solicitou soluções com regex. Lembrando que as tags se referem à pergunta, e não às respostas dadas.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Você tem, que criar uma função que faz isto, ou seja criar uma abstração para atender o requisito de ser um único comando. Mas como todo comando na linguagem não quer dizer que será uma única instrução a ser executada. A forma ingênua de fazer isto seria algo assim:

```
def mulipleReplace(text):
    for char in ".!?,":
        text = text.replace(char, "")
    return text
```

Mas isto é extremamente ineficiente porque a *string*  é imutável, então cada uma dessas operações gerará uma nova *string*, alocando memória que é algo caro, inclusive porque depois terá que copiar tudo, terá que liberar que chega ser mais caro ainda, e potencialmente poderá entupir a memória. A forma mais idiomática de resolver isto seria:

```
def mulipleReplace(text):
    return "".join([char if char in ".!?," else "" for char in text)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/TGAC9J). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zdltkrhf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/RemovePonctuation.py).

Esta forma cria uma lista de caracteres que interessa e depois transforma a lista em *string*.

Ainda pode fazer com RegEx, que eu não gosto até porque costuma ser ineficiente (não garanto nesse caso porque eu testo pouco em Python, se quiser teste todas opções antes de fazer, e tem várias outras formas de fazer o mesmo, mas tenho confiança que a anterior é muito rápida e provavelmente a mais rápida), algo assim:

```
texto = re.sub(".!?,", texto, "")
```

Não esquece que tem que importar o módulo `re`.

Moral da estória: programar não é enfileirar comandos que a gente nem entende o que faz, é entender todo o processo que ocorre no computador, na tecnologia que está usando e saber que para resolver problemas, a real profissão que exercemos é necessário ter metodologia e técnica. Tem várias formas de fazer, mas a maioria precisa de consciência, não pode ser só copiar e colar, e pode não existir pronto, ou o pronto não é ideal.

Answer (score 8):

## TL;DR:

```
import re
...
novo_texto = re.sub(r"\W", texto_original, "")
```

## Resposta completa:

O "replace" só consegue trocar uma única sequência  de texto por outra.
Para operações mais complexas de texto, entram em cena as chamadas "expressões regulares".

Expressões regulares são um mecanismo que existem em várias linguagens de programação, em Python inclusive, justamente para encontrarem padrões complexos dentro de texto,e procederem a alguma operação a partir dali (por exemplo, substituição).

O maior ponto negativo das mesmas é justamente um efeito colateral de sua maior força: para ter uma grande expressividade de descrever os vários padrões de texto, elas se tornnam complexas - ao ponto de serem descritas praticamente como uma outra linguagem de programação - uma "mini linguagem" dentro do Python.

[Em Python as expressões regulares são todas bem comportadas e bem definidas](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) - e não tem uma sintaxe especial. Basta importar o módulo `re` - e aí você tem várias funções que sempre tem o mesmo formato: você passa a expressão regular como uma string no primeiro parâmetro, o texto onde quer achar as ocorrências no segundo parâmetro, e, dependendo da operação mais parâmetros - no caso do `replace`, você precisa do método `re.sub`. (Em outras linguagens, como perl e javascript, expressões regulares usam sintaxes especiais em vez de serem escritas como chamadas de função - isso não facilita a leitura do código).

Então, se você for ler a documentação linkada acima, vai descobrir que você pode descrever uma "grupo de caracteres" dentro de `[]` na expressão regular - e qualquer um dos caracteres do grupo vai "dar match" na sua busca.

```
import re
...
novo_texto = re.sub(r"[,;&!?/.:]", texto_original, "")
```

Pronto - isso vai fazer o "replace" de qualquer caractere dentre `,;&!?/.:` pela string vazia `''`.

Se quiser eliminar *todos* os caracteres estranhos, exceto as letras, números e `_`, em vez de colocar todos os caracteres pode usar a expressão:

```
novo_texto = re.sub(r"\W", texto_original, "")
```

Um outro detalhe é que normalmente colocamos um `r` como prefixo das aspas da string que é passada como expressão regular: isso faz com que o Python não interprete o caractere `\` dentro dessa string como um escape do Python - isso é, a sequência `\n`, por exemplo, não vai ser "traduzida" antes mesmo do código ser executado, para o caractere de código `\x10` -  e sim, vai ser mantida como dois caracteres (['\', 'n'] ) literais. Isso é necessário por que o `\` também é muito usado dentro de expressões regulares.

Perceba que a documentação de expressões regulares pode parecer muito densa e confusa - e na verdade é! A não ser que você vá fazer um uso intensivo de regexps, pode levar *anos* para ficar confortável com seu uso, a ponto de criar as suas próprias sem ficar muito tempo fazendo testes antes - isso é normal. Se for usar bastante, o recomendado é treinar um pouco por dia - igual academia, até ter desenvoltura.

## Sem expressões regulares

Programaticamente também é possível substituir vários caracteres, mas aí realmente você precisa de um  `for` e chamar o replace uma vez para cada caractere ou sequência que deseja substituir. Dependendo da ocasião, pode ser muito demorado construir uma expressão regular que funcione bem, então você pode usar a sintaxe que já está acostumado.

A grande desvantagem de fazer isso nesse caso é que a string a ser substituída vai ser processada uma vez para cada caractere, enquanto que a expressão regular faz isso apenas uma vez - se for um ponto crítico de uma aplicação, por exemplo, uma aplicação Web que precisa fazer isso rápido, e ainda responder outras requisições várias vezes no mesmo segundo, *E* se o texto for grande (200_000 caracteres ou mais), pode fazer diferença. Pra textos pequenos (alguns Kilobytes) e poucos caracteres, numa operação que vai ser executada apenas uma vez (tratar uma amostra de texto que vai ser passada a um banco  ou engine de AI), absolutamente não faz diferença escrever o código em Python puro - o tempo de execução vai ser inferior a um décimo de segundo de qualquer forma:

```
texto = ...
...
for caractere in "!@#$%*()<>:|/?":
    texto = texto.replace(caractere, "")
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar um for para resolver o seu problema

```
texto = input("Digite um texto: ")

for c in ".!?,#@&%":
    texto = texto.replace(c, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode importar o módulo `string` e retornar os caracteres especiais com `string.punctuation:`

**Ex.:**

```
import string

for c in string.punctuation:
    texto = texto.replace('c','')
```

Bem similar ao código da Juliana Marques, o `string.punctuation` retorna todos esses caracteres:

```
!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_``{|}~)
```

Comment: Apesar da citação interessante  ao "string.punctuation', que acrescenta coisas que não estão nas outras respostas, o código está incorreto - a variável `texto` permanece inalterada, já que o `.replace` não altera a string "inplace", mas retorna uma cópia - e, se o fizesse, você só estaria substituindo a letra literal "c" no texto, não o conteúdo da variável `c`.

Comment: @jsbueno verdade!!! Não tinha percebido, vou editar. Grato!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
texto = '@#$#$@!#$@!#$ AB C D DFGSFGS DFGS #$%@#$%@#%$,..,.,..3452345.1'
caracter_esp = '.!?,@#%$ '
```

Aqui você entra com todos os carácteres que quer remover `caracter_esp = '.!?,@#%$ '`, caso queira remover os espaços é só adicionar um espaço (já inseri um espaço).

Você pode utilizar list comprehension:

```
nova_string = "".join([ caracter for caracter in texto if caracter not in caracter_esp])
print(nova_string)
```

Pode fazer utilizando filter:

```
outra_string = "".join((filter(lambda caracter: caracter not in caracter_esp, texto)))
print(outra_string)
```